# Screen sharing icon stuck in the menu bar

Tags: macos

I have a problem with the screen sharing icon being stuck in my menu bar. I've restarted my computer, `killall`'d my Dock and done anything else that's come to mind, but I can't get the item to go away.

[image]

It's the item on the far left. Here's a view of what the submenu looks like:

[image]

I can tell that it's a glitch in that I have identical settings on another Mac of mine and I don't have this problem. Also, it's quite odd that there's a random separator item in the submenu.

Comment: Did you try holding the Command key while dragging it off the bar?

Comment: That was extraordinarily cool and almost seemed too easy. Put that as an answer, sir; that was very helpful, thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Hold the <kbd>⌘</kbd> (command) key and drag the icon off of the bar.

Interesting tip: `/System/Library/CoreServices/Menu Extras/` is filled with various menus items that you cannot normally access, or are hard to find. Just double-click a `*.menu` item to add it to your menu bar.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like in Mavericks / OSX 10.9 you have to hold `Shift` + `Command` in order to drag the icon drag off the bar.